# How to get distinct JSON keys from a file full of JSON and redirect entries to specific directory structures?

Tags: java, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-streams, apache-kafka-connect

My requirement is that I get a JSON file from a Kafka topic in Kafka Stream, from which I need to group the JSON entries based on the keys and then dump those entries into different directories which are named after the keys.

For example:
I have a file with different JSON entries with Keys "A", "B", "A" & "C".

I need the above entries to be dumped into different directories. ie. Directory A will be created and the entry with JSON key "A" will go into a file in that directory. 
Directory B will be created and the two entries for the key "B" will go into a file in that directory and so on.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Kafka Streams is designed to write result back to Kafka. If you want to export data to a file system, you should use Kafka Connect instead. (Of course, you can still use Kafka Streams to prepare the data before you export it.)